# Prometheus HTTPS scheme "INVALID" is not valid start token

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

Trying to build an endpoint monitoring solution for a few public endpoints using Prometheus but I am stuck with the below error.

I am using Windows OS (Not sure if it's useful).

Below is my `prometheus.yml`

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "Viewer"    
    metrics_path: '/v6/latest/USD'    
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    static_configs:      
      - targets: ["open.er-api.com:443"]
```

And on the target monitoring page, I'm getting errors like the below -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you open full metric path in your browser or curl?
Do you use any open source exporter or you own?

Prometheus can only ingest this [format](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/) . Can you sure that format correctly or not?

Comment: Pardon me but ingestable formats are a bit confusing for me. It's my first use case to use Prometheus. Pasting this link which used for monitoring which returns json https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD

Comment: I am also not sure if I am overdoing it for just endpoint monitoring

Comment: Prometheus at the input wants to get the metric in the required format, it can’t just read the raw json. I think this article can help in your case:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/transforming-remote-json-into-prometheus-metrics-334d772df38a

Comment: The article is certainly helpful, I will give it a try.